# AX 2012 Customize LedgerJournalTrans insert

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I customize this method so that, under certain circumstances, the paymmode (payment method) is set to SEPA.

I tried this with the code:

```
this.PaymMode = "SEPA";
```

when i debug the scenario the system runs into this code, but nothing happens in the view, where i create the ledgerjournaltrans line.

I didn't find any other code which sets the PaymMode.

Anyone and idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code `this.PaymMode = "SEPA";` before `super();` in `Insert()` method. If you put this code before `super()` works fine.